# How do we come to know that the watch has failed in Redis

Tags: redis, jedis

I have one scenario where I want to log the key for which the watch failed. This is a java application. Following is the sequence of the statements in my code -

```
Multi 
Watch
Hmget
exec
```

and following is the code -

```
for (String key : coreKeys) {
            Transaction transaction = jedis.multi();
            jedis.watch(key);
            transaction.hmget(key, fields);
            redisData = transaction.exec();
...........
...........
```

The transaction is used in the scenario only because I want to know if any body changes the key. So the query that I have is how do we figure out that the watch has failed? Also after going through most of the examples on net, I have seen that the sequence of the statements should be

```
Watch
Multi 
Hmget
exec
```

but I will have to implement it with Watch as the second statement. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only know the watch has failed when EXEC returns.

WATCH itself always returns OK.

EXEC will return a null reply if it has failed because some watched data have changed. In your code you need to check whether redisData is an empty result, and attempt the transaction again if needed.